# How to put unicode chars in javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode, backend

I use BaaS for my Front-End. It allows me to upload a javascript file with my backend logic. I can use it via REST API on client side.
Among other services I've implemented a localization service. Strings are predefined like this:

```
var locals = {
"EN": {
    "1": "Home",
    "2": "Ready"
},
"BG": {
    "1": "Начало",
    "2": "Готово"
}
```

In this example I offer english and bulgarian string's localization.
The problem is that BaaS system doesn't respect Cyrillic (Unicode) characters.
When I upload the script with content as above, all cyrillic chars are replaced with "????".

I can use [this method](http://ecmanaut.blogspot.com/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html) to resolve the problem, but escape/unescape functions are deprecated. 
Is there any better solutions? 
What is the most effective way to avoid this problem?

Comment: Voted down - fine, but what is the reason

Comment: Could you explain what "BaaS" is?

Comment: Backend As A Service

Comment: I know what the abbreviation means, but is this some specific product, and can you point me to information on it?

Comment: I don't want to discover BaaS provider name. This unicode restriction will be fixed, but for now I have to find the best way to workaround the issue.

Comment: Find another provider who supports basic Internet standards such as Unicode. If your provider does not do this properly, then who knows what else is broken about their solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reference non-ASCII characters in a JavaScript file that isn't served Unicode-safe, use JS string literal character escapes: `\uNNNN` where NNNN is a the hex number of the UTF-16 code units associated with the string (same as the code point number for characters like these in the Basic Multilingual Plane).

```
"BG": {
    "1": "\u041d\u0430\u0447\u0430\u043b\u043e",
    "2": "\u0413\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0432\u043e"
}
```

List of code points for Cyrillic characters [here](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0400.pdf). You could also use Firefox's `toSource` method to work it out for you:

```
> 'Начало'.toSource()
(new String("\u041D\u0430\u0447\u0430\u043B\u043E"))
```

> When I upload the script with content as above, all cyrillic chars are replaced with "????".

Are you sure that is the “BaaS”'s fault? We can't really tell as you haven't told us what the service is or even what kind of service it is.

If it's a JS file you are fetching via Ajax you would need to save the file as UTF-8-encoded to be able to use non-ASCII characters without encoding them as above. If you are including it with a script element you also need to save the HTML page as UTF-8 and include a UTF-8 `meta charset` directive.

Comment: +1 Note that JavaScript supports [other escape sequences](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes) as well, such as `\xNN`. And to programmatically do the conversion (as part of a build script, perhaps?) use [_jsesc_](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsesc) ([demo](https://mothereff.in/js-escapes#1%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE)).